# How to keep everybody to their own buddypress profile and see noone else's?

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I have found a way to not show users in the members directory and not show the profiles when they are logged out via functions.php

```
 /**
 * Hide Members Directory from everyone.
 */
function buddydev_hide_members_directory_for_all() {
  if ( bp_is_members_directory() ) {
    bp_do_404();
    load_template( get_404_template() );
    exit( 0 );
  }
}

add_action( 'bp_template_redirect', 'buddydev_hide_members_directory_for_all' );
function buddydev_hide_members_directory_from_all_except_admin() {

  if ( bp_is_members_directory() && ! is_super_admin() ) {
    //should we add a message too?
    //bp_core_add_message( 'Private page.', 'error' );
    bp_core_redirect( site_url('/') );
  }
}
//Hide for non-logged-in users (public visitors)
function bp_logged_out_page_template_redirect() {
if( ! is_user_logged_in() && (is_page( 'members' ) || bp_is_user()) ) {
wp_redirect( home_url( 'login' ) );
exit();
}
} add_action( 'template_redirect', 'bp_logged_out_page_template_redirect' );
```

However, I can't find a way to keep them out of other people's profiles as soon as they are logged in. Does anybody have an idea how to keep everybody to their own profile and noone else's?

Answer (score 0):

Check if they are an administrator.
Check if they are viewing their own profile.
Try:

```
function bp_logged_out_page_template_redirect() {
    if( ! is_user_logged_in() && (is_page( 'members' ) || bp_is_user()) ) {
       wp_redirect( home_url( 'login' ) );
       exit();
    } else {
       if ( ! is_super_admin() && ( bp_is_user() && ! bp_is_my_profile() ) ) {
           wp_redirect( home_url() );
           exit();
       }
    }
} add_action( 'template_redirect', 'bp_logged_out_page_template_redirect' );
```